# MySQL, subquery use not in

Tags: mysql, sql

everyone, I encounter with a small question, but I don't know the reason, so, anyone can give me any clue?

Here is the question:

> Write a query to find the names (first_name, last_name) of the employees who >are not supervisors.

Here is the schema:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME  | LAST_NAME   | EMAIL    | PHONE_NUMBER       | HIRE_DATE  | JOB_ID     | SALARY   | COMMISSION_PCT | MANAGER_ID | DEPARTMENT_ID |
```

And, here is my solution:

```
select first_name, last_name 
from employees 
where job_id not in (select manager_id from employees ) order by first_name;
```

Now, I'am sure it's not right. But I still can not figure out the reason.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you tell whether a person *is* or *is not* a supervisor? Is anyone who is referred to through `manager_id` automatically a supervisor? In that case you could do

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees a WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employees b WHERE b.manager_id=a.employee_id)
```

to find all employees who are *not* supervisors.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick advice. I use the manager_id to make sure the person is a supervisor.
And, actually my question is, why my solution is not right? Really thank you!

Comment: Well, it seems to me that your `job_id` does not contain a reference to someone's employee-id but more likely to some kind of job or post that the person is reponsible for. So your query should more likely be looking for the `employee_id` *not to be listed*  in `employees`like: `select first_name, last_name 
from employees 
where employee_id not in (select manager_id from employees ) order by first_name`.